# Why do Windows commands allow `-` and `/` switches?

Tags: windows, command-line

```
> shutdown /?
> Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/f]
```

The windows `cmd.exe` command `shutdown` only documents forward slash `/` switches, but it accepts dash `-` switches as well. For instance, both work:

```
shutdown /s /t 0
shutdown -s -t 0
```

When was this added and why?

Comment: Slashes: Windows's original option syntax. Dashes: To make it more POSIX like

Comment: @ThomasEding, not quite "original", it is an RSX-11 (and other similar DEC systems) legacy (through CP/M)

Comment: And (MS|PC)-DOS, which preceded Windows.

Comment: @Blrfl: MS-DOS followed CP/M.

Comment: @kevincline:  Windows, having originally been built atop MS-DOS, got its option signifier there.  MS-DOS, which started life as Seattle Computer Products' 86-DOS, was a CP/M clone for the 8086.  Just filling in the historical gap between CP/M and Windows.

Comment: Unless you can get one of the original designers of MS-DOS here, I dont see how this is actually answerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would venture that multiple escape characters are supported for switches so that users that are used to a particular escape character can still use the application from the command-line.

Answer (score 11):

Slashes are Windows's original option syntax and not all windows commands accept the dash-options.

With `Dir /?` you the list of the options for `dir`.

But with

```
Dir -?
```

you get a *file not found*-message (tested with Windows XP) (Same with `dir -w`...).